# According to Roman Catholic Church, why should we pray to Mary and not just through her to her Son?

Tags: catholicism, virgin-mary, mariology

The Bible does not mention anywhere that we should pray to God ***through*** Mary.

Obviously she's Mother of God, and we owe her that, but even Jesus teaches to pray to God Himself.

But why does the Roman Catholic Church teach that we should pray ***to*** Mary and not just ***through*** her to her Son?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. They're related, but the questions are not the same. However, this question does seem to make some assumptions about Roman Catholic belief that I'm not sure are correct.

Comment: From what I understand (and I could be mistaken), the question appears to be about the difference between praying ***to*** Mary and praying ***through*** her to her Son. I've edited the question reflecting this.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will read the answered questions posted.

Comment: "Holy Mary, mother of God, pray for our sinners, now and at the hour of our death. Amen." This is part of the Catholic church's "holy rosary" and it's to be said 53 times. Not coincidental on the number. The answer is in a very specific document. This question is answerable.

Comment: @Daisy Intercessory prayers are covered in the answer AthanisusofAlex provided.  While the question is answerable, I think it was already answered.

Comment: is it worth bringing up the point that Sola Scriptura is not a Roman Catholic doctrine?

Comment: hi Korvin, do you mind cutting and pasting that post; I can't find it and I was responding to Lee's comment that the question is different. Thanks

Comment: @Daisy: This answer is quite comprehensive. http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/32619/900